# jainsip processResponse not called

Tags: jain-sip

I have successfylly used jainsip to register clients.  The method processRequest is working.  I am sending an Invite from the proxy to the phone and the phone is ringing.  The source port of the invite is 5060 and the ip the ip of the server.  I have used a sniffer to verify that 100Trying and 180Ringing are sent from the client to the server/proxy on port 5060.  There are two clients registered on the server and as mentioned, processRequest is working, but the 100Trying and 180Ringing responses arenot picked up by the SIpListener or the method processResponse just isn't called.  I am using these jars:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.sip</groupId>
  <artifactId>jain-sip-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.sip</groupId>
  <artifactId>jain-sip-ri</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.167</version>
</dependency>
```

I am sending invite using this code:

```
ClientTransaction clientTransaction = sipProviderStatic.getNewClientTransaction(inviteRequest);
clientTransaction.sendRequest();
```

The registrations are going throug fine so it is not a firewall problem, I even tried turning it off.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

first thing is you have to redirect the port if you are testing in two emulators by sending request and getting response like the following:

go to command than enter "telnet localhost 5554" and enter same for another emulator

than enter "redir add udp:5070:5070" for server code and

than enter "redir add udp:5060:5060" for client code which is sending request ... than you can able to see the request and response between those two emulators

Comment: I verified that the client is responding correctly by sniffing. The responses go to the server ip address on port 5060 udp on which the jainsip listener is operating and correctly receiving requests.